# Is there any way to remove the yui reset.css from Magento 1.6?

Tags: magento

I'm working on a Magento theme in version 1.6.1 and for some reason the default installation has a bunch of yui scripts and stylesheets loading last in the `<head>`. One of these is the yui reset.css which should be loaded as the first stylesheet, not the last, and it's overriding all kinds of styles.

I can't for the life of me find where these includes are happening. I know that it's related to the getCssJsHtml() function but I don't see it being added anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through your theme layout.

Just add the local.xml file to your theme's layout dir with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
   <reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/reset.css</name></action>
   </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: the reference should be `head`, not `root`.

Comment: The includes are external references so I don't think they can be removed via XML update. These are the references before the closing head tag:`<link href="http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/build/reset/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/imageloader/imageloader-min.js" type="text/javascript">
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/fonts/fonts-min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: where and how were they included?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to figure out, they were there after a clean installation and I can't find where they are being included anywhere.

Comment: In this case this can't be the clean installation. Any extensions installed?

Comment: Dick, you're right. I had forgotten that I added an extension for including external css and script references. The default extension install includes the yui css and js files by default. I'm not sure why I didn't notice earlier. Thanks for the help and sorry for being a bonehead.